# Getting null in console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm getting value as null in console if i use annotation to get the output, this has also occured in previous programs also & if i use  context:annotation-config in xml file i will get exceptions. please help.

This is Address class

```
package com.springcore.auto.wire.annotation;

public class Address 
{
    private String street;
    private String city;
    
    public String getStreet() 
    {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) 
    {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public String getCity() 
    {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Address [street=" + street + ", city=" + city + "]";
    }
}
```

This is Emp class

```
package com.springcore.auto.wire.annotation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Emp 
{
    @Autowired
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() 
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) 
    {
        System.out.println("Setting value using set");
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Emp(Address address) 
    {
        super();
        this.address = address;
        System.out.println("Setting value using constructor");
    }

    public Emp() 
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Emp [address=" + address + "]";
    }
}
```

This is Main method class

```
package com.springcore.auto.wire.annotation;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springcore/auto/wire/annotation/autoconfig.xml");
        Emp emp1 = context.getBean("emp1", Emp.class);                                              
        System.out.println(emp1);
    }
}
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="=http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:p="=http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
 <bean class="com.springcore.auto.wire.annotation.Address" name="tempaddress" >
    <property name="street" value="Temp street" />
    <property name="city" value="Mysore" />
 </bean>

 <bean class="com.springcore.auto.wire.annotation.Emp" name="emp1"  /> 

</beans>
```

i'm getting this output :

```
Emp [address=null]
```

Comment: where is your constructor in Address that actually takes those parameters you've put in your xml?

Comment: Ofcourse you will as you didn't enable annotation processing, you need to add `<context:annotation-config />` else the `@Autowired` will be ignored.